# Find key-value min number in a dictionary Python

Tags: python

I have this dictionary

```
my_dict = {'x':500, 'y':5874, 'z': 560}    
key_min = min(my_dict.keys(), key=(lambda k: my_dict[k]))   
print('Minimum Value: ',my_dict[key_min])
```

I want to print key correspond to minimum value. How can I do that?

```
print(my_dict.keys()[key_min])
```

Comment: You already have that key in `key_min`, no?!

Comment: @sara, the answer is `print(key_min)`, as @deceze pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min`

```
min(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)

In [20]: my_dict = {'x':500, 'y':5874, 'z': 560}

In [21]: min(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
Out[21]: 'x'
```